# Remove method lines in IntelliJ

Tags: java, editor

Is there a way to remove the red lines shown on the picture? They obviously indicate where a method or class is closing itself

I could not find any solution regarding this...

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Atc.png

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Preferences>Editor>Genral>Breadcrumbs` and uncheck indent guides